# How to Counting Word support and confidence with lucene

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, information-retrieval

I want to use Lucene in Java applicaton to calculate word support and confidence.
I have over 500 .txt document, and an ArrayList contains two term, term i and term j

```
The formula for counting Confidence

Dti-tj/Dti

Dti-tj: Total document contains term i,term j
Dti : Total document contains term i

The formula for counting Support

Dti-tj/D

Dti-tj = Total document contains term i,term j
D = Total Document in the collection
```

Is it possible using Lucene to search and counting the word?
What class i have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply search for your two terms, term `i` and term `j`, and get your counts from the `totalHits` return from the search.

```
int docCount = indexReader.numDocs();
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

Query queryI = new TermQuery(new Term(fieldName, termI));
Query queryJ = new TermQuery(new Term(fieldName, termJ));

Query queryIJ = new BooleanQuery();
queryIJ.add(new BooleanClause(queryI, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
queryIJ.add(new BooleanClause(queryJ, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));

int countI = searcher.search(nqueryI, maxDocs).totalHits;
int countIJ = searcher.search(, maxDocs).totalHits;

float confidence = (float)countIJ / (float)countI;
float support = (float)countIJ / (float)docCount;
```

Comment: maybe the BooleanClause.Occur.Should must be edited to Occur.Must because the document must contains the two term

Comment: As I read it, I though `Dti-tj` was meant to represent a union.  If it was meant to be an intersection, then you would want to use `Occur.MUST` instead, yes.